# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "um zu" und "zum"

Tags: standard-german

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "zum" und "um zu" in diesem Satz

> Es gibt viele Wege um eine E-Mail an diese Firma zu schreiben.
>
> Es gibt viele Wege zum Schreiben einer E-Mail an diese Firma.

Comment: Hallo Milad, gute Fragen in diesem Forum demonstrieren eine gewisse eigene Anstrengung des Fragenden, das Problem zu lösen. Vielleicht möchtet du deine eigenen Gedanken und Erwägungen hinzufügen?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatisch richtig und stilistisch sauber müsstest du sagen und schreiben:

> Es gibt viele Wege, eine E-Mail an diese Firma zu schreiben.

(Beachte auch das Komma!)

Die beiden von dir notierten Varianten dagegen sind grammatisch falsch (Satz 1) bzw. stilistisch problematisch (Satz 2). Allerdings kann es durchaus sein, dass du sie im lockeren Gespräch hin und wieder hörst, insbesondere Satz 2:

> (?) Es gibt viele Wege zum Schreiben einer E-Mail an diese Firma.

Ein solcher Satz kann in formloser mündlicher Kommunikation als normal (genauer: stilistisch unauffällig) gelten und wäre dann gegebenenfalls sogar Ausweis besonderer Vertrautheit mit der deutschen Umgangssprache jenseits der  Schulbuchweisheit. In schriftlichen Kommunikationsformen solltest du solche eindeutig umgangssprachlichen Sätze jedoch nicht verwenden.

Weitere Beispiele für formal korrekte (schriftsprachliche) Sätze mit "zu/zum/um zu" und ihre mündlich-schludrigen Brüderchen:

Mündlich (schludrig, aber akzeptiert):

> Ich habe keine Lust zum Kochen.
>
> Es gibt keinen Grund zum Angsthaben.
>
> Ich gehe in die Stadt zum Einkaufen.

Schriftlich (und sauber mündlich):

> Ich habe keine Lust zu kochen.
>
> Es gibt keinen Grund, Angst zu haben.
>
> Ich gehe in die Stadt, um einzukaufen.

In Alltagssituationen mündlicher Kommunikation kann es vorkommen, dass die "saubere" Variante gestelzt, überbemüht oder nach Schulbuchdeutsch klingt.

**Nebenbemerkung: die Sinnfrage...**

Der Satz *Es gibt viele Wege, eine E-Mail an diese Firma zu schreiben* ergibt, so für sich genommen, eigentlich wenig Sinn, denn es fällt schwer, eine Situation im Leben zu finden, wo man in sinnvoll einsetzen könnte. Warum? Der *Weg*, eine E-Mail zu schreiben ist stets der gleiche: Man setzt sich an den Computer und schreibt sie. Ob man das im betriebseigenen E-Mail-System macht oder in einem Online-Tool bereitgestellt von den großen Datenkraken, ist vermutlich hier nicht, was du unter "Weg" verstehst, und selbst wenn, würde man das anders ausdrücken, nämlich unter spezifischer Nennung der Alternativen.

Vielleicht meinst du gar nicht "Weg", sondern "Art und Weise", und zwar im Sinne von "Ausdrucksweise"? Man kann einen höflichen Brief schreiben, man kann einen barschen Brief schreiben, man kann einen freundlichen Brief schreiben, man kann einen sachlichen Brief schreiben, man kann einen unverschämten Brief schreiben... was meintest du konkret?

Comment: Vielen Dank christian, korregieren sie bitte diesen satz?Zum Schreiben einer E-Mail an diese Firma, gibt es viele Wage.

Comment: Der Satz lautet. *Zum Schreiben einer E-Mail an diese Firma gibt es viele Wege.* Das heißt, dein Satz war richtig bis auf das fehlende Komma sowie den Tippfehler in "Wege". Beachte aber, dass dies erneut ein Satz nur für den legeren mündlichen Gebrauch ist.